# Attempt to use Promises to delete records

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

Here is a simple task I would like to accomplish on Parse.com with Cloud Code.
The task consists to delete a Unit and what is related to it.

One Unit has several Sentences related to it and each Sentence has one or more Translations.
So when the task is performed, the Unit as well as the Sentence and Translations should be deleted.

I have a strong feeling I should be using Promises (and chain them up) in order to do what I want in a good manner.

Below is the code I wrote, but it works only partially (The translations are deleted, not the rest).

```
Parse.Cloud.define("deleteUnitAndDependencies", function(request, response) {
    var unitListQuery = new Parse.Query("UnitList");
    unitListQuery.equalTo("objectId", request.params.unitID);
    unitListQuery.equalTo("ownerID", request.params.userID);
    unitListQuery.find().then(function(resUnit) {
        var sentenceListQuery = new Parse.Query("SentenceList");
        sentenceListQuery.equalTo("unit", resUnit[0]);
        return sentenceListQuery.find();
    }).then(function(resSentence) {
        var translatListQuery = new Parse.Query("TranslatList");
        for (i = 0; i < resSentence.length; i++) {
            var query = new Parse.Query("TranslatList");
            query.equalTo("sentence", resSentence[i]);
            translatListQuery = Parse.Query.or(translatListQuery, query);
        }
        return translatListQuery.find();
    }).then(function(resTranslat) {
        for (iT = 0; iT < resTranslat.length; iT++) {
            resTranslat[iT].destroy({});
        }
    });
});
```

I surely need to add some lines of code like:

```
  resSentence[x].destroy({});
```

and:

```
  resUnit[0].destroy({});
```

The problem is that I do not quite see where is the adequate place for that.

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Your code is not well-indented and is hard to read which makes answering it hard.

Comment: I did my best so that the reader does not have to scroll left and right to read. The code is inspired by this https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-chaining, which does not have so much indentation either, unless I am looking at it a different way.

Comment: OK. I see. The bad quotes came from TextEdit. I was going to change the .then lines, but you were faster than me. Thanks anyway. I hope now some people will point me to the solution. I am quite a beginner with "Promises" :)

Answer (score 1):

Collect the objects to be deleted then use `Parse.Object.destroyAll(someArray);` to delete all at once.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this I like to use a scope variable to hold things for later use.

```
var scope = {
  sentences: [],
  units: []
};

// later inside then block...
  scope.sentences.push(resSentence[i]);

// ...now we have them collected safely
.then(function() {
  return Parse.Object.destroyAll(scope.sentences);
})
```